# Kettle csv import, set null value in rows with format errors

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I created an import job that reads data from a CSV file and save them (with some changes) in a Mysql DB.
The Job works but sometimes I've dirty input files and if I set a format for example for dates, I've an exception that prevents to elaborate the file.

As you see in the image, I set a format for dates.

[image]

Unfortunately sometimes that values is not filled right. I'd like to set an empty date if the value is not a date. Instead so far I get just an exception:

[image]

What's the best way to set a null value for the cells that don't resepct the given format?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using Text file input instead of CSV file input. It has this logic embedded.

[image]

Comment: Beware that you're ignoring errors instead of managing them. That means the records with an incorrect format might not be stored in the DB. You should have an error handling step to convert the faulty dates to whatever you want and then store them in the DB.